# Why is my code giving an infinite while loop/crashing?

Tags: python, pygame, time

I have this large code that produces buttons that are meant to be clicked.

```
import pygame
import csv
import time 
from datetime import datetime
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
#from picamera2 import Picamera2 , Preview
#from libcamera import controls
#from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder

# Constants
ITI = 2 # Inter-trial interval in seconds

# Initialize pygame starts
pygame.init()

# Set the dimensions of the screen
screen_width = 1275
screen_height = 750

# Set the colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# Set the font
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 20)

# Set the button properties
button_radius = 70
button_x_spacing = 400
button_y_spacing = 200

# Set the button positions
button_positions = [
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing),
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 200),
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 400)
]

# Inputs
trials = int(input("Number of trials: "))
AnimalName = input("Animal Name: ")
Trial_Duration = int(input("Trial Duration (s): "))

# Setting up Camera
#camera = Picamera2()
#vidconfig = camera.create_video_configuration()
#camera.configure(vidconfig)
#encoder = H264Encoder(bitrate=10000000)
#vidname = f"{AnimalName}_WCST_S3_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}_Video.h264"
#camera.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)
#camera.start_recording(encoder,vidname)
#camera.annotate_text = f"{AnimalName}_WCST_S3_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}"


# Initialize the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

# Set the caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Marmoset Buttons")

# Set the clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Set the counters
correctleft = 0
correctmiddle = 0
correctright = 0
incorrectleft = 0
incorrectmiddle = 0
incorrectright = 0
trialnum = 0
timeouts = 0

# Set the lists
timelistleft = []
timelistmiddle = []
timelistright = []
summarysequence = []

# GPIO Setup
#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# Psuedorandom sequence of numbers
sequence = [1,1,2,2,1,2,1,0,1,1, 1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1,1, 2,1,0,1,2,1,1,0,1,2, 2,1,0,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,
           1,1,0,1,1,1,2,0,2,1, 2,1,0,1,0,1,1,2,2,1, 1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,2,2, 1,1,2,1,1,2,1,0,1,1,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,2,0,2,1, 0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0, 1,1,0,1,1,2,1,2,1,0, 2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,
           1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,2, 1,2,1,0,1,2,2,2,1,0, 1,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,0,
           1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1, 0,1,2,2,1,1,1,0,1,1, 1,0,1,2,0,1,0,1,1,2, 0,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,0,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0, 1,2,2,1,0,1,1,2,0,1, 1,0,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0, 1,0,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,
           1,2,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,0, 1,1,0,1,2,1,1,2,1,0, 1,2,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0, 1,2,0,2,1,2,1,0,0,1,
           1,1,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,1, 0,1,2,0,1,2,1,2,1,0, 1,0,1,2,1,1,2,0,1,2, 0,0,1,0,2,1,2,1,2,1,
           1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,0, 1,2,1,1,0,2,1,2,1,1, 1,2,2,1,1,2,1,0,0,1, 2,1,2,1,0,2,1,2,0,0,
           1,0,1,1,2,2,1,0,1,0, 0,1,2,1,1,0,1,2,0,1, 1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,0, 1,2,0,0,2,1,0,2,1,1,
           1,1,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,1, 2,1,0,1,1,0,1,2,1,0, 0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1, 2,1,0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,
           1,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1, 2,1,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2, 1,0,1,2,1,2,0,1,2,2, 2,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,1,
           1,2,1,0,1,2,0,2,2,2, 1,2,2,1,1,0,1,1,0,0, 1,1,0,1,0,0,1,2,1,2, 1,0,2,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,
           1,2,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1, 1,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,1,1, 1,2,1,0,2,2,1,2,0,1, 1,1,2,2,1,0,1,2,1,0,
           1,2,0,1,1,0,1,1,2,1, 1,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,1,0, 1,2,0,0,0,1,2,2,0,1, 0,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,
           1,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1, 1,2,1,0,1,1,2,1,0,2, 1,0,2,2,1,0,1,0,2,1, 1,0,2,1,2,1,1,0,0,1,
           1,2,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,1, 1,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,0, 1,2,1,2,2,1,0,1,0,0, 2,1,0,2,0,1,0,1,2,1,
           1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1, 1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1,0, 2,1,2,2,1,0,1,0,1,1, 2,1,2,0,1,2,1,2,0,0,
           1,1,2,0,2,1,2,1,1,0, 1,2,1,0,0,1,1,2,1,2, 1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,0,0, 1,2,1,0,0,2,1,0,2,1,
           1,0,1,1,2,1,2,0,1,2, 2,1,0,1,1,0,1,2,1,0, 0,1,0,1,2,1,1,2,1,0, 2,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1]

# Truncating list
#trials = int(input("Number of trials: "))
n = len(sequence)
for i in range(0, n - trials):
    sequence.pop()

# Setting up CSV title
thedatetime = datetime.now()
thetime = thedatetime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
title = f"{AnimalName}_WCST_S3_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}.csv"

# Write headers to csv file
data = open(title, 'w')
writer = csv.writer(data)
writer.writerow(["Trial#", "Event Code", "Time"])

time_start = time.time()

# For loop parsing through sequence 
for i in sequence:

    trialnum += 1
    summarysequence.append(i)

    # Writing summary csv 
    if trialnum%10 == 0:
        if trialnum == 10:
            title2 = f"{AnimalName}_WCST_S3_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}_Summary.txt"
            summary = open(title2, "a+")
            summary.write(f"Trial Duration: {Trial_Duration}\n")
            summary.write(f"ITI: {ITI/1000}\n")
        meanleft = sum(timelistleft) / len(timelistleft)
        meanmiddle = sum(timelistmiddle) / len(timelistmiddle)
        meanright = sum(timelistright) / len(timelistright)
        #summary = open(title2, "a+")
        summary.write(f"Completed Trials (saved every 10th): {trialnum}\n")
        summary.write("Sequence: " + str(summarysequence) + "\n")
        summary.write(f"Correct: {correctleft},{correctmiddle},{correctright}\n")
        summary.write(f"Incorrect: {incorrectleft},{incorrectmiddle},{incorrectright}\n")
        summary.write(f"Total Reward: {correctleft+correctmiddle+correctright}\n")
        summary.write(f"Total No Reponses: {timeouts}\n")
        summary.write(f"Mean Reaction Times: {meanleft}, {meanmiddle}, {meanright}\n")
        summary.write("------------------------------------------------------------\n")

    # Delay between buttons
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.update()
   
    time_end = time.time() + ITI
    while time.time() < time_end:
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            if i == 0:
                writer.writerow([trialnum, 210, time.time() - time_start])
                time_end += 0.5
            elif i == 1:
                writer.writerow([trialnum, 211, time.time() - time_start])
                time_end += 0.5
            elif i == 2:
                writer.writerow([trialnum, 212, time.time() - time_start])
                time_end += 0.5

    # While loop variable 
    correct = False

    # Starts Timer 
    #start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    start_time = time.time()
    
    # Writing the button in csv file
    timedisplay = time.time()
    writer.writerow([trialnum, i, timedisplay - time_start])

    # Loops while button isn't correct 
    while correct == False:

        # Time out for 15 seconds 
        seconds = (time.time() - start_time)
        if seconds >= Trial_Duration:
            timeouts +=1
            timenow = time.time()
            writer.writerow([trialnum, 250, timenow - time_start])
            break

        # Checks when screen is touched 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                # Distance between point touched and button 
                distance_button = pygame.math.Vector2(button_positions[i]) - pygame.math.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

                # Checks if distance is within button 
                if distance_button.length() < button_radius:

                    correct = True
                    timecorrect = time.time()
                    writer.writerow([trialnum, 150, timecorrect - time_start])

                    # Reward
                    #GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
                    #GPIO.output(12,GPIO.HIGH)
                    #time.sleep(0.1)
                    #GPIO.output(12,GPIO.LOW)
                    #GPIO.cleanup()

                    # Counts which buttons were pressed 
                    if i == 0:
                        timecorrect = time.time()
                        timedifference = timecorrect - timedisplay
                        timelistleft.append(timedifference)
                        correctleft += 1
                    elif i == 1:
                        timecorrect = time.time()
                        timedifference = timecorrect - timedisplay
                        timelistmiddle.append(timedifference)
                        correctmiddle += 1
                    elif i == 2:
                        timecorrect = time.time()
                        timedifference = timecorrect - timedisplay
                        timelistright.append(timedifference)
                        correctright += 1

                # Counts when touch was outside of button 
                elif distance_button.length() > button_radius:
                    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if y <= (screen_height/3):
                        incorrectleft += 1
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 201, timenow - time_start])
                    elif y <= 2*(screen_height/3):
                        incorrectmiddle += 1
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 200, timenow - time_start])
                    elif y > 2*(screen_height/3):
                        incorrectright += 1
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 202, timenow - time_start])   

        # Draws the button 
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, button_positions[i], button_radius)
        pygame.display.update()

# Closing objects 
data.close()
summary_contents = summary.read()
print(summary_contents)
summary.close()
#camera.stop_recording()
#camera.stop_preview()
```

This snippet here is the part that I am working on

```
 time_end = time.time() + ITI
    while time.time() < time_end:
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            if i == 0:
                writer.writerow([trialnum, 210, time.time() - time_start])
                time_end += 0.5
            elif i == 1:
                writer.writerow([trialnum, 211, time.time() - time_start])
                time_end += 0.5
            elif i == 2:
                writer.writerow([trialnum, 212, time.time() - time_start])
                time_end += 0.5
```

I have an interval in between when the button is pressed and the next one shows up. I am trying to get it to increase that interval if it senses the mouse is clicked. if the mouse is being held it will continuously add 0.5 seconds to the time until nothing is being pressed. Currently, the code is crashing once it gets to the while loop. I'm not sure why this is as all documentation i've seen says to use pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

Comment: I'm not familiar with pygame, but ... `while time.time() < time_end:
` ...  `time.time()` is unlikely to change within a single frame (at least not unless you're doing something that will intentionally hang the game).